# Django. Model function for avatar

Tags: python, django

I wrote a function for the profile model so that if the profile does not have an avatar, there will be a default picture. But this function works only when the profile has a  picture, and when it does not exist, there is the absence of any image tag . How can I write the function correctly so that it displays a picture from the media folder of the project directory?

```
 @property
    def avatarURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.avatar.url
        except:
            url = 'media/avatar.svg'

        return url

── ./media
│   ├── ./media/avatars
│   ├── ./media/avatar.svg
│   └── ./media/images
```

HTML

```
 <img src="profile.avatarURL"  alt="Profile picture class="round"/>
```

Comment: `<img src="{{ profile.avatarURL }}"`

Comment: Also instead of `url = 'media/avatar.svg'` use `url = '/media/avatar.svg'`. Notice the leading `/`. Otherwise it will not work on many urls (Without leading slash a relative url is assumed to start from the current url / directory)

Answer (score 0):

I use a if function to set another picture if the profile pic is empty. Try somehtin like this

Template:

```
   {% if user.profile.photo %}
     <span class="account-user-avatar"> 
   <img src="/media/{{ user.profile.photo }}" alt="user-image" class="rounded-circle">
     </span>
        {% else %}
        <span class="account-user-avatar"> 
   <img src={% static 'images/users/user.png' %} alt="userimage" class="roundedcircle">
       </span>
      {% endif %}
```

Model:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_image_file_extension 
   
photo = models.ImageField(_("profile picture"), upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/', 
height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None, blank=True, validators= 
[validate_image_file_extension])
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I know this method and use it now, but I would like to use a more general and less code method.